# ¿Cómo puedo formatear un valor de tipo Date de yyyy/mm/dd a dd/mm/yyyy con jQuery y viceversa?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

¿Cómo puedo tratar este tipo de datos? Por favor, se los agradecería mucho.

```js
$('#fechaNacimiento').val({
  dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
});
```

Answer (score 2):

desafortunadamente JQuery no cuenta con una funcion que permita hacer directamente lo que tu necesitas, asi que mi sugerencia es un metodo propio que haga el parseo en esta propuesta te muestro como parsear de la forma "DD-MM-YYYY" ya tu podras modificarlo segun tus necesidades:

```
$.date = function(dateObject) {
    var d = new Date(dateObject);
    var day = d.getDate();
    var month = d.getMonth() + 1;
    var year = d.getFullYear();
    if (day < 10) {
        day = "0" + day;
    }
    if (month < 10) {
        month = "0" + month;
    }
    var date = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;

    return date;
};
```

de este modo lo que queda por hacer es :

```
$.date(yourDateObject);
```

y esto te devuelve lo que necesitas.

Comment: ¿cuando quiero ingresar el valor desde el formulario, habria ningun proble en almacenarse en la BD o tendria que hacer de nuevo el parseo?